# Get request is not authorized when CSRF is disabled in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Spring Security basic authentication works if I don't add the following

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

After I add this code piece a GET request without an Authorization header gets the response while I expect a response saying Unauthorized. Before adding this configuration GET response gets `401`.

The only change is the above class; nothing else was changed.

Comment: check http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/request-url").permitAll()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `.anyRequest().authenticated()`, it means, all request must be authenticated. If you want to add an exemption add something like `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/js/**", "/css/*", "/images/**").permitAll()` this will not be authenticated.

Sample Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/js/**", "/css/*", "/images/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```